# How to tgz all items in a directory and encrypt it using GnuPG on the fly?

Tags: linux, bash, tar, gnupg, for-in-loop

I'm searching for a solution to tgz all items of a directory and in that step I want to encrypt it using GnuPG on the fly.

To tgz all items in the directory I use

```
for i in *; do tar cfvz $i.tgz $i; done
```

I think I have to pipe it through `gpg` like this

```
| gpg -z 0 --always-trust --encrypt -r mail@mail.com > "file".tgz.gpg
```

but where do I have to put the `gpg` call? All what I tried resulted in an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're fine with storing the intermediate file on the hard disk, just encrypt this (and possibly delete it afterwards). The resulting script would be something like

```
for i in *
do
  tar cfvz $i.tgz $i
  gpg -r mail@mail.com --encrypt $i.tgz # Include the other options as needed
  rm $i.tgz # If you want to
done
```

If you want to perform the operation without an intermediate unencrypted file on the disk, make sure tar is dumping the file to stdout instead of writing it to a file (by not using the `-f` flag):

```
for i in *; do tar cvz $i | gpg -r mail@mail.com --encrypt > $i.tgz.gpg; done
```

Comment: hi, `for i in *; do tar cvz $i | gpg -r mail@mail.com --encrypt > $i.tgz.gpg; done` that's the solution i search for. thx!

Comment: What would be the decrypt equivalent?

Comment: Mostly replace `--encrypt` by `--decrypt` and remove the recipient option.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to tar up the files individually, with one tarball per file.

tar is perfectly capable of tarring up all the files into one tarball. E.G:

```
tar czvf - * | gpg -z 0 --encrypt -ruser@example.com >/tmp/msg.gpg
```

Comment: mh that dosnt works for me :(
`gpg: conflicting commands` 
`tar: -: Cannot write: Broken pipe` 
`tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now` 

but thx for feedback

Comment: Works for me. This error simply indicates some gpg command line option mess-up. The basic mechanics -- of tarring up multiple files and piping the result to gpg, happened here.